# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')

Tags: reactjs, element

I am trying to create an event to delete elements on button click but get the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')"

```
const Todo = ({ text, todo, todos, setTodos }) => {
  const deleteHandler = () => {
    setTodos(todos.filter((el) => el.id !== todo.id));
  };

  return (
    <div className="todo">
      <li className="todo-item">{text}</li>
      <button className="complete-btn">
        <i className="fas fa-check"></i>
      </button>
      <button onClick={deleteHandler} className="trash-btn">
        <i className="fas fa-trash"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: todos probably isn't an array. Only arrays have the filter property.

Comment: There is no property called __id__

Answer (score 0):

you have to check if element exists or not, i am hoping its array with `id` property, if its `undefined`, so no point in calling `.fliter` on it, it will surely throw error, call only when it have data, like this will fix the issue, i do this in my project too,

```
const deleteHandler = () =>{
   setTodos(todos && todos.filter((el) => el.id !== todo.id));
};
```

you can do this instead,

```
const deleteHandler = () =>{
   if(todos ){
      setTodos(todos.filter((el) => el.id !== todo.id));
   }
};
```

Comment: This sets todos to either true or false. How does that help?

Comment: @EmilKarlsson problem is not callin filter on undefined, so check before you calling, let me know if it worked

Comment: first option, brings error 'setTodos' is not a function , second option ... nothing happens on button click

Comment: todos probably isn't an array. Only arrays have the filter property